# Java Synchronised Blocks for static variables

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a shared resource which is accessible by two distinct threads, is it a good practice if I create a `synchronized` block synchronizing an `Object` lock accessing the shared resource and on my distinct Thread inside the `void run()` method, have another `synchronized` block synchronizing the very same `Object` lock and inside that block accessing the same shared resource? I could see programmatically that it works, but is it a good practice?

Comment: What sort of shared resource? Stateful statics are nearly always a problem, and the usual approach would be to create a wrapper class that hides the actual shared resource and enforces synchronized access to it (see `Collections.synchronizedList`).

Comment: Well, it is a actually Set, but it is inside a singleton and I have to use this set in multiple threads

Comment: That was simply a reference for an example of this pattern.